# My CSS values does not reflect the values in my JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to read display value (`display:none;` or `display:block;`) of a div (div id="navmenu") from JavaScript. But when I set the style values in same html file I'm able to read, but when I set the style values in the linked CSS style sheet it does not read (result is just blank).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="navmenu">
  <p>This is a box of 250px * 250px</p> 
 </div><!--navmenu-->
<!-------------------------------------------------------------------> 
<script>
 function display(elem) {
   return elem.style.display;
 }
 alert(display(document.getElementById('navmenu')));
</script>
<!-------------------------------------------------------------------> 
</body>
</html>
```

[image]
and css

```
#navmenu {
    display:block;
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    background-color:#3CC;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `elem.style.display` property only reports a display property that is set directly on the DOM object.  It does not report a style that is inherited from a style sheet.

To get a style value including those from a style sheet, you can use [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

```
function display(elem) {
    return getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("display");
}
```

Comment: What is the benefit of using `getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("display")` versus `getComputedStyle(elem, null).display`? Just curious

Comment: @jdphenix - some CSS property names are not legal JS identifiers (like those that contain a `-`), but they will all work with `getPropertyValue()`.

Comment: Nice, so you don't have to mangle them to pascalCase.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `getComputedStyle()`:

```js
 function display(elem) {
   return window.getComputedStyle(elem).display;
 }
 alert(display(document.getElementById("navmenu")));
```

```html
<div id="navmenu">
  <p>This is a box of 250px * 250px</p>
</div>
<!--navmenu-->
```

Answer (score 0):

> The HTMLElement.style property returns a CSSStyleDeclaration object that represents the element's style attribute. See the CSS Properties Reference for a list of the CSS properties accessible via style.

The style property is not useful for learning about the element's style in general, since it represents only the CSS declarations set in the element's inline style attribute, not those that come from style rules elsewhere, such as style rules in the  section, or external style sheets. To get the values of all CSS properties for an element you should use window.getComputedStyle() instead.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

so your solution is `window.getComputedStyle()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic function for querying the display style of any element with [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) - it simplifies the interface a bit and caches the computed style object.

```
function getStyle(query) {
  var elem = document.querySelector(query),
      cs = window.getComputedStyle(elem,null);
  return {
     get : function(prop) {
        return cs.getPropertyValue(prop);
     }
  }
}
```

Usage: just query the element using [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors) for example in your case the the element has ID "navmenu", the query goes like

```
var s = getStyle( "#navmenu" );

s.get("display");
s.get("color"); // etc...
```

Works IE9+.