# Cannot understand the behavior of element.style.color

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the following code the color of the element para1 is set to green by means of the internal styling at the beginning.

If I click on the buttons the very first time "console.log(elem.style.color)" inside the "function changeColor" will not return the color green. The second time and so on the color of the element is returned.

```js
function changeColor(newColor) {
  var elem = document.getElementById("para1");
  console.log(elem.style.color);
  elem.style.color = newColor;
}
```

```css
.mypara1{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<p id="para1" class="mypara1">Some text here</p>
<button onclick="changeColor('blue');">blue</button>
```

Why is the color set by the internal styling not returned?

Comment: [`element.style` is a reference to inline styles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style), it is not changed by styles set in `<style>` or in a linked css file.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4a3bbazu/2/

Comment: I think  .mypara1{ color: green; } should be  #para1{ color: green; }

Comment: @JonSG sorry, this was a typo. I missed the class of the element.

Comment: @DerGroncki : Does my answer solve your problem, or you are looking for something else?

Comment: [css values does not reflect in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148873/css-values-does-not-reflect-in-javascript)

Comment: @ParagBhayani: Patrick Evans already answered my question. Thank you.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Your comment answered my question. Please change your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that [`elem.style` returns the style that is directly applied on a DOM element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) (e.g. in the HTML, or through `elem.style`), not the style resulting from a CSS selector.

If you want to get the computed style, that takes into account the CSS rules, you need to use [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle). Note that the result may be slightly different from what has been entered (e.g. with chrome, colors are always given as rgb values).

```js
function changeColor(newColor) {
  var elem = document.getElementById("para1");
  console.log(getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue("color"));
  elem.style.color = newColor;
}
```

```css
.mypara1{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<p id="para1" class="mypara1">Some text here</p>
<button onclick="changeColor('blue');">blue</button>
<button onclick="changeColor('red');">red</button>
```

Here is an example with the style attribute set in the HTML instead of the CSS. See as `console.log` works the first time now even when using `elem.style`.

```js
function changeColor(newColor) {
  var elem = document.getElementById("para1");
  console.log(elem.style.color);
  elem.style.color = newColor;
}
```

```html
<p id="para1" class="mypara1" style="color: green;">Some text here</p>
<button onclick="changeColor('blue');">blue</button>
<button onclick="changeColor('red');">red</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort.Your answer is very useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

In your style definition, you are setting the attribute `color` of the class `mypara1` to green.
When you take a look at the first time the `<p>` is rendered, it has a color assigned to it via its `class`, not via its `id`, so it indirectly sets the color.
To illustrate:

1. Go to your jsfiddle link
2. Right click on "some text here" `<p>`
3. Click on Inspect on the window menu
4. View the Styles tab in the opened dev tools new window.
5. See that class `mypara1` has `color: green`, there is no `element.style`
6. Click on either "blue" or "red" buttons
7. See how there is a new property for `element.style` with your desired color.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function changeColor(newColor) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("para1");
    console.log(elem.style.color);
    elem.style.color = newColor;
  
  }
```

```html
<p id="para1" class="mypara1" style="color:green">Some text here</p>
<button onclick="changeColor('blue');">blue</button>
<button onclick="changeColor('red');">red</button>
```

Take a Look at this Code snippet, i have added an inline style "color:green" to the

Tag, now it returns green at the first time of function call itself.

Comment: Just take a look now.

Comment: I think OP wants to print the previous color. Not the color to set.